# Strange NSPasteboard and TextEdit interaction

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, appkit

I am drag-dropping a string from two places in my app. One from a custom `NSView` and one from a `NSTableDataSource` delegate. The first one allows me to drag text into the TextEdit application, the second one does not. I can drag from both to other apps such as Terminal or TextMate. As far as I can tell, I'm using close to identical code for both.

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong. It's working in principle because I can drag to some apps. But what's going on with TextEdit?

From the custom NSView:

```
(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString *testString = @"TEST";

    NSImage *dragImage;
    NSPoint dragPosition;

    NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];

    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSStringPboardType, nil] owner:nil];
    [pboard setString:testString forType:NSStringPboardType];

    dragImage = // blah
    dragPosition = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

    [self dragImage:dragImage
                 at:dragPosition
             offset:NSZeroSize
              event:theEvent
         pasteboard:pboard
             source:self
          slideBack:YES];
    }
}
```

From the table delegate:

```
(BOOL)tableView: (NSTableView *)aTableView writeRowsWithIndexes: (NSIndexSet *)indexes toPasteboard: (NSPasteboard *)pboard
{
    NSString *testString = @"TEST";

    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSStringPboardType, nil] owner:nil];
    [pboard setString:testString forType:NSStringPboardType];

    return YES;
}
```

If I print out the pboard's types for the first one:

```
"public.utf8-plain-text",
NSStringPboardType,
```

And for the second:

```
"public.utf8-plain-text",
NSStringPboardType,
```

Likewise, the content for the first:

```
2010-11-16 13:56:01.832 XXX[1654:a0f] public.utf8-plain-text:TEST
2010-11-16 13:56:01.838 XXX[1654:a0f] NSStringPboardType:TEST
```

And second

```
2010-11-16 13:56:05.623 XXX[1654:a0f] public.utf8-plain-text:TEST
2010-11-16 13:56:05.623 XXX[1654:a0f] NSStringPboardType:TEST
```

So as far as I can tell, the two should be behaving identically. But they're not. Ideas?

Comment: Is the object that implements `NSTableViewDataSource` a visible feature in the interface? When you say you are dragging from that object, do you mean that you are dragging from the tableView?

Comment: Josh - I'm sorry this was too long ago to remember. I've moved on since then.

Comment: No problem, I figured it might've been too old a problem. I just thought I had an inkling of what the trouble was.

Comment: Well, please feel free to share your inkling! I'm sure others will come this way.

Comment: You're quite right. However, I just fiddled around with it and it wasn't what I thought it was. Oh, well.